# UIImagePickerController With Camera Option both portrait and landscape mode in iPhone SDK (Is ti possible to change by using CameraOverlayView?)

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiimagepickercontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I was taking photos through `UIImagePickerController`. When I captured a photo in Portrait mode, it was correctly displayed. But when i captured photo in Landscape mode it automatically rotated into portrait mode and was then displayed.

What are the possible ways to display a captured photo in Landscape mode when i capture photo in Landscape orientation.

Thanks in advance.

Is it possible if using `CameraOverlayView`??????

Comment: at where you are displaying the photo ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a single method for orientation purposes and call it everytime -BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOri‌​entation is called.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the image with its `UIImageOrientation` attribute using the method:

```
- (id)initWithCGImage:(CGImageRef)imageRef scale:(CGFloat)scale orientation:(UIImageOrientation)orientation
```

This way, you can control the zoom as well, with the variable `scale`. You can refer to the various [orientation values](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIImageOrientation) and use device orientation at the time of capturing the `UIImage`